# Matrix free eigenvalue computation

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a linear function of Euclidean vectors , is there a way to compute it's eigenvalues and eigenvectors without assuming an arbitrary basis and matrix algebra.

For example a linear function  T= ax(u x a) + bx(u x b) is called a tensor because it represents some property of a system .

It would be useful to have a less cumbersome method then matrix computations for eigenvalues of such tensors  and something that is more geometrical, because eigenvectors of such tensors represent the principal moments of  inertia needed to solve the Euler equation for an arbitrary body.

I've heard of mohrs algorithm but I think it only applies for 2d